# Como pegar o último (max) tabindex, de um formulário html, usando jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Preciso pegar o último 'tabindex' de um formulário para quando o usuário clicar 'tab' ou 'enter' voltar para o primeiro.

Segue código atual:

```
$(':input').keydown( function(event) {

    if ( (event.which === 13 || event.which === 9) && !event.shiftKey ) {
        node = $(this);
        currentIndex = node.attr('tabindex');
        // if ( currentIndex > 0 ) {
        if ( currentIndex > 0 && currentIndex < **MAX_TABINDEX** ) 
            event.preventDefault();
            currentIndex++;
            $('[tabindex=' + currentIndex + ']').focus();
            $('[tabindex=' + currentIndex + ']').select();
        } else {
            $('[tabindex=1]').focus();
            $('[tabindex=1]').select();
        }    
    }
```

Alguma ideia?

Comment: Ou você pode verificar se o último elemento está com o focus, se sim, ao pressionar TAB ou ENTER manda o focus pro primeiro...

Comment: @Earendul como identifico o último elemento? Digo, de maneira dinâmica e não apenas colocando o nome do objeto, tem como? Algo do tipo 'last(':input');'

Comment: Assim: `$("input:last")`. https://api.jquery.com/last/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode verificar se o último elemento está com o focus, se sim, ao pressionar <kbd>TAB</kbd> ou <kbd>ENTER</kbd> manda o focus pro primeiro. Exemplo:

```js
$(':input').keydown( function(event) {
  if ( (event.which === 13 || event.which === 9) && !event.shiftKey ) {
    var idx = $(':input').index(this) + 1; //index atual
    var idx_total = $(':input').length; // index do ultimo
    event.preventDefault();
    if (idx == idx_total) { // se for o ultimo volta pro primeiro
      $('input:eq(0)').focus();
    }
    else {
      $('input:eq('+idx+')').focus(); // senao focus no proximo
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><input id="entrada1" type="text"></input></p>
<p><input id="entrada2" type="text"></input></p>
<p><input id="entrada3" type="text"></input></p>
<p><input id="entrada4" type="text"></input></p>
```

Comment: Fiz apenas uma alteração pois como meu primeiro campo com 'tabindex' é oculto, utilizei  { $('[tabindex=1]').focus(); } ao invés de 'input:first'. Obrigado!!! =)

Answer (score 1):

Aqui voce monta um array de tabs

```
 var size=$('#ui-tabs >ul >li').size();
```

Logo o ultimo vai ser o size -1;